Script to empty 1st & 2nd stage recycling bins from all sites in SharePoint
I'm looking for a way to automate emptying the recycling bins (1st & 2nd stage) from all sites in our SharePoint (Online) collection.
From searching, I've found solutions that no longer work (presumably because of MFA), and solutions that only empty the recycling bin of one site.  And some present both.
I've found a PnP script that will iterate through all sites, but Clear-PnPRecycleBinItem seems to only work on the site you are currently connected to via Connect-PnPOnline, so this is unusable to me (too many sites to have to go through).
Can anyone help on this?

I decided to give the -Connection parameter of Clear-PnPRecycleBinItem a try.  Considering we have 42 SharePoint sites (as of current) and we have MFA enabled, I was expecting a headache, but it actually didn't turn out that bad: it only prompted 3 times.  Here's my final script.  If someone ever comes around with something that works even better, that'd be great. :)
I also changed the Try-Catch from the examples given so it won't stop the whole script just because one of the urls throws an exception.
$AdminSiteURL = "https://domain-admin.sharepoint.com"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminSiteURL -Interactive

$SitesCollection = Get-PnPTenantSite

ForEach($Site in $SitesCollection) 
{
    Try {
        Clear-PnPRecycleBinItem -All -Force -Connection (Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Site.Url -Interactive)
        Write-host -F Green "Recycle bin cleared:" $Site.Url
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message ":" $Site.Url
    }
}
Disconnect-PnPOnline


I suggest you try the following two methods:
1.
#Parameter
$TenantAdminURL = "https://Crescent-admin.sharepoint.com"
 
#Connect to Admin Center
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TenantAdminURL -Interactive
    
#Get All Site collections 
$SiteCollections = Get-PnPTenantSite  
   
#Loop through each site collection
ForEach($Site in $SiteCollections)
{
    Clear-PnPRecycleBinItem -All -Force
}

Reference:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/get-all-site-collections-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html
2.
#Parameter
$AdminSiteURL = "https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com"
 
Try {
    #Connect to Admin Center
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminSiteURL -Interactive
  
    #Get All Site collections 
    $SitesCollection = Get-PnPTenantSite
  
    #Loop through each site collection
    ForEach($Site in $SitesCollection) 
    { 
        Clear-PnPRecycleBinItem -All -Force
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
}

Reference:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/12/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-iterate-through-all-site-collections.html#sharepoint-online-pnp-powershell-to-loop-through-sites

Thanks, but I already knew how to loop through all of the sites (I provided a link to such a script which was your 2nd link you provided).  The issue, as I stated, was that Clear-PnPRecycleBinItem seemed to only work with the active Connect-PnPOnline, meaning I would need to make a connection request to each of our (current) 42 sites to clear all of their recycling bins, of which we have MFA enabled....
That said, I've made an attempt at using the -Connection parameter to Clear-PnPRecycleBinItem and the result wasn't actually that bad.
